Capacitor : How to set-up the ios team signing parameter for Pods
I have many iOS developer profiles in my mac so many team IDs.
When I build a capacitor project, the default "ios/App/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" is generated with default settings and so without the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM info.
I have the error "ios/App/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj Signing for "CustomBrowser" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
".
So, there is a way to set-up this data directly in the project ?
Currently, I shall to set-up directly with XCode the team or create a copy of Pods.xcodeproj file with right data and replace it before the build of app.

So, the solution is in this issue https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402
For me, update CocoaPods solve the issue.
